# CSS font-variation-settings not working

Tags: css

I'm currently experimenting with variable fonts. My first test was to experiment with the font-variation-settings directive, but it seems that is not working. Both on Codepen:

https://codepen.io/DailyMatters/pen/LrBvmz

This is my current CSS (it seems like the font is being loaded correctly from dropbox):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SourceSans';
  src: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmonith639cs931/SourceSansVariable-Roman.ttf') format('truetype');
}

html {
  font-family: 'SourceSans', sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-variation-settings: "wght" 999, "wdth" 125;
}
```

But also on Chrome.

As much as I change the "wght" axis, nothing happens. I did same tests with this same font using @font-face, and it worked on Chrome. Any reason this is not working with font-variation-settings?

Comment: Are you sure the font link works from dropbox? When I tried, it defaulted back to Arial

Comment: Seems like both my browser and Codepen re unable to load the font file due to CORS. any idea on how can I solve this? Mainly on Codepen, as I would like to make a demo of this.

Comment: i ran into the same issue on Chrome a while back. all of a sudden `@font-face` just stopped working. i think it may be a bug in Chrome itself or something.

Comment: Neither your Source Sans nor google fonts version include a `wdth` axis. You can check all availabe variable design axes in javaScript as explained here ["How do I get a variable font axes with javascript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58795927/how-do-i-get-a-variable-font-axes-with-javascript/73922586#73922586).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the `font-stretch` and `font-weight` properties with the range you would like to use for your variation to your `@font-face` declaration in your stylesheet.

Also you have to make sure that the font you are using actually supports those variations. The variations may limit depending on the font you use. See for example [the support for variations with Google fonts here](https://fonts.google.com/).

[image]

I tried to make your Codepen work but the server where you load the font responds with a 404 error when trying to load the font.

My guess is you should try something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SourceSans';
  font-weight: 400 900;
  font-stretch: 75 100;
  src: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmonith639cs931/SourceSansVariable-Roman.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

See also for more information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

and

https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/using_type/loading_variable_fonts_on_the_web