# How do I get a variable font axes with javascript?

Tags: javascript, fonts

I'm beginning work on an editor that allows you to play with [variable fonts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Fonts/Variable_Fonts_Guide#Variable_Fonts_what_they_are_and_how_they_differ), however a very simple problem stumped me:

Variable fonts have *variation axes* which allow you modify the visual properties of the typeface. A simple one is weight, which allows you to go from light to black weight, for example.

The problem is that I don't know beforehand which *variation axes* are available in the font, so I can't dynamically display the correct sliders for the font.

**Is there programmatic way in JavaScript to find the variation axes of variable fonts?**

What have I tried you ask? Well, I've built this:

https://method.ac/font-tester/

The relevant code is this:

```
    input.addEventListener("input", function(){
      text.style["font-variation-settings"] = "'wght' " + input.value;
    })
```

But what I'm really looking to solve is something like...

```
    var fontAxes = [how?];
    fontAxes.forEach(axis => {
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      // customize input
      input.addEventListener("input", function(){
        // change axis
      })
    })
```

Comment: Vanilla JS? No. The native APis for fonts are incredibly terrible. You're better off either writing a small parser for FVAR information, or using something like opentype.js or fontkit

Comment: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/520

Comment: In the mean time, I sat down to revisit Font.js which at this point will quite happily report which axes exist for variable fonts in ttf/otf, plain/woff/woff2 versions (e.g. [in Adobe Source Code Pro](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EJYFdGAUwAApUx-?format=png&name=360x360) we just get `wght`). The code is currently in the `remastered` branch of https://github.com/Pomax/Font.js but will replace master in a few days when I add in the remaining parsing for the common table format and add in the text measurement functionality that the original Font.js was for.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Oh that looks really promising, I'll wait for the release since I'm not in a rush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Retrieve axes data via LibFont.js

As mentioned in his comment you can retrieve the design axes data parsing a font file with the [LibFont](https://github.com/Pomax/lib-font) library (the successor of font.js).

#### Example 1: Get all design axes info

```js
// retrieve font data after all required assets are loaded (e.g for decompression)
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {

  // Example font: roboto flex
/* api url: 
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Flex:opsz,slnt,wdth,wght,GRAD,XTRA,YOPQ,YTAS,YTDE,YTFI,YTLC,YTUC@8..144,-10..0,25..151,100..1000,-200..150,323..603,25..135,649..854,-305..-98,560..788,416..570,528..760*/
  let fontUrl = "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotoflex/v9/NaPccZLOBv5T3oB7Cb4i0zu6RME.woff2";
  let fontFamily = "variable Font";
  getAxisInfo(fontFamily, fontUrl);
});

function getAxisInfo(fontFamily, fontUrl) {
  let font = new Font(fontFamily, {
    skipStyleSheet: true
  });
  font.src = fontUrl;
  font.onload = (evt) => {
    let font = evt.detail.font;
    let otTables = font.opentype.tables;
    let fontname = otTables.name.get(1);

    // get variable font axes
    let axes = otTables.fvar.axes;
    let axesInfo = [];
    axes.forEach((axis, a) => {
      let axisName = axis.tag;
      let min = axis.minValue;
      let max = axis.maxValue;
      let defaultValue = axis.defaultValue;
      axesInfo.push(`name:"${axisName}"; min:${min}; max:${max}; default:${defaultValue};`);

    })
    let fontAxisString = fontname + '\n' + axesInfo.join('\n');
    fontAxisData.textContent = fontAxisString;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- add brotli decompression needed for woff2 -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lib-font@2.4.0/lib/unbrotli.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lib-font@2.4.0/lib-font.browser.js" type="module"></script>

<pre id="fontAxisData">
```

This above example retrieves the font data for "Roboto Flex".

**The essential steps are:**

Get a `font` object specifying a font file path/url like so:

```
let font = new Font('variableFontfamilyName');
font.src = "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotoflex/v9/NaPccZLOBv5T3oB7Cb4i0zu6RME.woff2";
```

Retrieve axes info from the `fvar` table records:

```
let otTables = font.opentype.tables;
let axes = otTables.fvar.axes;
```

#### Example 2: Inspect all design axes with preview

```js
// init first font
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  let firstFont = fontSelect.children[0];
  let fontUrl = firstFont.value;
  let fontFamily = firstFont.textContent.trim();
  loadFont(fontFamily, fontUrl);
});

upload.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  // Encode the file using the FileReader API
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = () => {
    let fileName = file.name;
    let format = fileName.split('.').pop();
    let arrayBuffer = reader.result;
    loadFont(fileName, arrayBuffer)
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
})

fontSelect.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  let current = e.currentTarget;
  let fontUrl = current.value;
  let fontFamily = current.options[current.selectedIndex].textContent.trim();
  if (fontUrl) {
    loadFont(fontFamily, fontUrl);
  }
})


function loadFont(fontFamily, fontUrl) {
  let format = '';
  let fontSrc = '';
  let font = {};
  // if fontUrl is array buffer
  if (fontUrl.byteLength) {
    format = fontFamily.split('.').pop();
    format = format == 'ttf' ? 'truetype' : format;
    fontFamily = fontFamily.replaceAll('.' + format, '');
    font = new Font(fontFamily, {
      skipStyleSheet: true
    });
    font.fromDataBuffer(fontUrl, fontFamily);
    // array buffer to base64
    let base64 = arrayBufferToBase64(fontUrl);
    fontUrl = `data:font/${format};charset=utf-8;base64,${base64}`;
    fontSrc = `src: url(${fontUrl});`;
  }
  // if fontUrl is file url
  else {
    format = fontUrl.split('.').pop();
    format = format == 'ttf' ? 'truetype' : format;
    font = new Font(fontFamily);
    font.src = fontUrl;
    fontSrc = `src: url(${fontUrl} format('${format}'));`;
  }


  font.onload = (evt) => {
    let font = evt.detail.font;
    let otTables = font.opentype.tables;
    let fontname = otTables.name.get(1);
    fontNameCaption.textContent = `${fontname}`;

    // get variable font axes
    let axes = otTables.fvar.axes;

    let cssArr = [];
    AxesWrp.innerHTML = '';
    let axesInfo = [];
    axes.forEach((axis, a) => {
      let axisName = axis.tag;
      let min = axis.minValue;
      let max = axis.maxValue;
      let defaultValue = axis.defaultValue;

      //create range sliders according to min/max axes values
      let rangSliderLabel = document.createElement('label');
      let rangSlider = document.createElement('input')
      rangSlider.setAttribute('type', 'range');
      rangSlider.setAttribute('min', min);
      rangSlider.setAttribute('max', max);
      rangSlider.setAttribute('value', defaultValue);
      rangSlider.setAttribute('step', 0.1);
      rangSliderLabel.textContent = axisName + ': ';
      AxesWrp.appendChild(rangSliderLabel)
      rangSliderLabel.appendChild(rangSlider);

      // set default style
      cssArr.push(`"${axisName}" ${defaultValue}`);
      axesInfo.push(`name:"${axisName}"; min:${min}; max:${max}; default:${defaultValue};`);

      // update values by range sliders
      rangSlider.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        cssArr[a] = `"${axisName}" ${e.currentTarget.value}`;
        fontPreview.style.fontVariationSettings = cssArr.join(', ');
        variationProp.textContent =
          `{font-variation-settings: ${fontPreview.style.fontVariationSettings} }`;
      })
    })
    console.log(axesInfo.join('\n'))

    //let fontVariationOptions = `font-variation-settings: ${cssArr.join(', ')}`;
    fontPreview.style.fontVariationSettings = cssArr.join(', ');
    //console.log(fontVariationOptions)


    variationProp.textContent =
      `{font-variation-settings: ${fontPreview.style.fontVariationSettings} }`;

    // append style for preview
    let fontStyle = 'normal';
    let fontWeight = 400;
    fontStyleEl.textContent = `
            @font-face{
                font-family: "${fontFamily}";
                ${fontSrc}
                font-style: ${fontStyle};
                font-weight: ${fontWeight};
            }
            .fontPreview{
                font-family: "${fontFamily}";
            }
            `;
  }
}


function arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
  let binary = '';
  let bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  for (let i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
  }
  return btoa(binary);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

label {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.fontPreview {
  font-size: 10vmin;
  line-height: 1em;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- add brotli decompression needed for woff2 -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lib-font@2.4.0/lib/unbrotli.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lib-font@2.4.0/lib-font.browser.js" type="module"></script>

<style id="fontStyleEl"></style>

<p><label>Select font:</label>
  <select type="text" id="fontSelect" value="" list="fontList">
    <option value="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/recursive/v35/8vIK7wMr0mhh-RQChyHuE2ZaGfn4-zal.woff2">Recursive
    </option>
    <option value="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotoflex/v9/NaPccZLOBv5T3oB7Cb4i0zu6RME.woff2">Roboto Flex
    </option>
    <option value="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v34/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVZ0b.woff2">Open Sans
    </option>
  </select>

  <label>Load font: <input type="file" id="upload"></label>

</p>
<div id="AxesWrp"></div>

<div class="preview">
  <p><span id="fontNameCaption"></span>
    <pre id="variationProp"></pre>
  </p>
  <div class="fontPreview" id="fontPreview" contenteditable>FontPreview: Type something</div>
</div>
```

### Update 2023: get axes data via opentype.js

Apparently [opentype.js](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js) has included **fvar** table data to the font object.
State 2023: opentype.js currently doesn't support any rendering functionality for variable fonts.
It's also lacking support for **CFF2** fonts.

However you can adapt the previous function to work with opentype.js.

```js
let fontFamily = '';
let fontSrc =
  "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotoflex/v9/NaPccZLOBv5T3oB7Cb4i0zu6RME.woff2";
let fontFaceSrc = fontSrc;

// processs default font
getVFAxes(fontSrc);

upload.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  // Encode the file using the FileReader API
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = () => {
    let fileName = file.name;
    let format = fileName.split('.').pop();
    let arrayBuffer = reader.result;
    let base64 = arrayBufferToBase64(arrayBuffer);
    fontFaceSrc = `data:font/${format};charset=utf-8;base64,${base64}`;
    console.log(fontSrc);
    getVFAxes(file);
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
})


fontSelect.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  let current = e.currentTarget;
  let fontUrl = current.value;
  fontFamily = current.options[current.selectedIndex].textContent.trim();
  if (fontUrl) {
    getVFAxes(fontUrl);
  }
})

async function getVFAxes(fontSrc) {
  let font = await loadFont(fontSrc);
  let fontFamily = font.tables.name.fontFamily.en;
  let axes = font.tables.fvar.axes;
  let cssArr = [];

  // reset axis sliders
  AxesWrp.innerHTML = "";
  let axesInfo = [];

  axes.forEach((axis, a) => {
    let axisName = axis.tag;
    let min = axis.minValue;
    let max = axis.maxValue;
    let defaultValue = axis.defaultValue;


    //create range sliders according to min/max axes values
    let rangSliderLabel = document.createElement("label");
    let rangSlider = document.createElement("input");
    rangSlider.setAttribute("type", "range");
    rangSlider.setAttribute("min", min);
    rangSlider.setAttribute("max", max);
    rangSlider.setAttribute("value", defaultValue);
    rangSlider.setAttribute("step", 0.1);
    rangSliderLabel.textContent = axisName + ": ";
    AxesWrp.appendChild(rangSliderLabel);
    rangSliderLabel.appendChild(rangSlider);

    // set default style
    cssArr.push(`"${axisName}" ${defaultValue}`);
    axesInfo.push(
      `name:"${axisName}"; min:${min}; max:${max}; default:${defaultValue};`
    );

    // update values by range sliders
    rangSlider.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      cssArr[a] = `"${axisName}" ${e.currentTarget.value}`;
      fontPreview.style.fontVariationSettings = cssArr.join(", ");
      variationProp.textContent = `{font-variation-settings: ${fontPreview.style.fontVariationSettings}}`;
    });

    fontPreview.style.fontVariationSettings = cssArr.join(', ');
    variationProp.textContent =
      `{font-variation-settings: ${fontPreview.style.fontVariationSettings} }`;

    // append style for preview
    let fontStyle = 'normal';
    let fontWeight = 400;

    fontStyleEl.textContent = `
            @font-face{
                font-family: "${fontFamily}";
                src: url(${fontFaceSrc});
                font-style: ${fontStyle};
                font-weight: ${fontWeight};
            }
            .fontPreview{
                font-family: "${fontFamily}";
            }
            `;

  });
}

/**
 * opentype.js helper
 * Based on @yne's comment
 * https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js/issues/183#issuecomment-1147228025
 * will decompress woff2 files
 */
async function loadFont(src) {
  let buffer = {};
  let font = {};
  let ext = "woff2";
  let url;

  // 1. is file
  if (src instanceof Object) {
    // get file extension to skip woff2 decompression
    let filename = src.name.split(".");
    ext = filename[filename.length - 1];
    buffer = await src.arrayBuffer();
  }

  // 2. is base64 data URI
  else if (/^data/.test(src)) {
    // is base64
    let data = src.split(";");
    ext = data[0].split("/")[1];

    // create buffer from blob
    let srcBlob = await (await fetch(src)).blob();
    buffer = await srcBlob.arrayBuffer();
  }

  // 3. is url
  else {
    // if google font css - retrieve font src
    if (/googleapis.com/.test(src)) {
      ext = "woff2";
      src = await getGoogleFontUrl(src);
    }

    // might be subset - no extension
    let hasExt =
      src.includes(".woff2") ||
      src.includes(".woff") ||
      src.includes(".ttf") ||
      src.includes(".otf") ?
      true :
      false;
    url = src.split(".");
    ext = hasExt ? url[url.length - 1] : "woff2";

    let fetchedSrc = await fetch(src);
    buffer = await fetchedSrc.arrayBuffer();
  }

  // decompress woff2
  if (ext === "woff2") {
    buffer = Uint8Array.from(Module.decompress(buffer)).buffer;
  }

  // parse font
  font = opentype.parse(buffer);
  return font;
}


function arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
  let binary = '';
  let bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  for (let i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
  }
  return btoa(binary);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

label {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.fontPreview {
  font-size: 10vmin;
  line-height: 1em;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<style id="fontStyleEl"></style>

<p><label>Select font:</label>
  <select type="text" id="fontSelect" value="" list="fontList">
    <option value="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/recursive/v35/8vIK7wMr0mhh-RQChyHuE2ZaGfn4-zal.woff2">Recursive
    </option>
    <option value="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotoflex/v9/NaPccZLOBv5T3oB7Cb4i0zu6RME.woff2">Roboto Flex
    </option>
    <option value="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v34/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVZ0b.woff2">Open Sans
    </option>
  </select>

  <label>Load font: <input type="file" id="upload"></label>

</p>
<div id="AxesWrp"></div>

<div class="preview">
  <p><span id="fontNameCaption"></span>
    <pre id="variationProp"></pre>
  </p>
  <div class="fontPreview" id="fontPreview" contenteditable>FontPreview: Type something</div>
</div>



<!-- fontello woff2 to truetype conversion -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wawoff2@2.0.1/build/decompress_binding.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/opentype.js@latest/dist/opentype.min.js'></script>
```